# SQL order numbers alphabetically

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Currently I have an SQL query that selects some columns and then does ORDER_BY ID.

Simple enough.  The output is i.e. 92, 101, 105, 200, 1234

Problem is, the program I am trying to use it in will only accept input in alphanumerical order.  That means I need it to be 101, 105, 1234, 200, 92.

How can I modify the SQL query to order the numbers alphanumerically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to convert the column to a `VARCHAR` then sort on that

```
SELECT OrderID
FROM dbo.FooTable
ORDER BY CAST(OrderID AS VARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: I may be upvoting also because of varchar(max). But seriously, a number 255 long is huge.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS - `varchar(max)` would allow numbers up to 2 billion digits long. Which seems complete overkill as the longest possible number in SQL Server is `numeric(38,x)` so `varchar(40)` should be plenty.

Comment: @MartinSmith @Valamas I usually use VARCHAR(MAX) to be pedantically safe, but you're totally right it is overkill. The max `BIGINT` value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) or 19 characters long

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by converting the number to a character string:

```
order by cast(col as varchar(255))
```

For instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just re-cast the data type for your ID column:

```
order by cast(ID as varchar(10))
```

This should work on most systems